# eloquent relation in laravel with json

Tags: php, json, laravel, relation, eloquent

suppose i have two tables(Team and User) in my database . in Team table i have data like "["5","6","7","9","10","26","27"]"(json) , and in users table i have id column in which data is like serial no(Auto_increment .1,2,3 ....nth).is it possible a relation which finds a if json has that single key in it.
i have a loop statement which has the result that i want but i want that data in relation the code is :

```
foreach($model as $key => $value){
        $user_data = User::whereIn('id',json_decode($value->member_ids))->get();
        $model[] = $user_data;
      }
```

Comment: Your Question Is not Clear. Can You tell me the Column names of both the tables and what exactly you want.

Comment: members_ids = "["5","6","7","9","10","26","27"]" , id = 1,2,...nt ( which is auto increment)

Comment: So you want to find if any id i.e., 1,2 .. is present in  "["5","6","7","9","10","26","27"]" or in members_ids column or not. Is that what you want.?

Comment: yes exactly . if available then return me as a relation else return relation null.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$arr = json_decode("["5","6","7","9","10","26","27"]");
if (in_array(5, $arr )) {
    // code 
}
```

Comment: appreciate your reply , but sir i need it as a collection relation